# Connection Time out error while parsing hbm file

Tags: java, hibernate, ant

I am facing this weird issue while opening hbm file. I am using hibernate3.jar. I also verified that there is only one hibernate3.jar in classpath and it contains hibernate mapping dtd file.

I tried to put code and exception here but StackOverFlow engine continuously throwing some error.
Code and exception is given at [link] https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1029004.

I also tried by specifying docBuilder.setEntityResolver(new DTDEntityResolver());

I was running it via Apache Ant and behind proxy.
Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the file path?

Comment: filepath is path of file located on same machine i.e. C:/home.hbm.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting proxy values as export

```
ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"
```

didn't work. So, I set the proxy values in Ant's build file as given in ant documentation and it worked.

```
<property name="proxy.port" value="80"/>
<property name="proxy.user" value=""/>
<property name="proxy.pass" value=""/>
```